# SqlAlchemy: Insert New Row and Modify Another: "Can't attach instance <ObjectT>; another instance with key is already present in this session"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have to simultaneously insert a row and also modify another (set its `ACTIVE=N`) on submission. The new row being added is a copy of the old one, with a new ID. I use Python's `copy.deepcopy` to save the old object, and then I erase the current one's `id` to make it eligible for insertion with a new sequence value. Both actions should then occur in the transaction.

```
# First fetch existing agreement. Initially "postApproveOldAgreement" is None.
postApproveOldAgreement = None
agreement = db_session.query(AgreementT).filter(AgreementT.id == form['someId']).first()
...

if someCondition:
   postApproveOldAgreement = copy.deepcopy(agreement)
   postApproveOldAgreement.active = 'N' # Modify old agreement
   agreement.id = None # Make this one eligible for new insertion

# Continue filling out the "agreement" object
...

# Insert/Modify and Commit 
db_session.add(agreement)
if postApproveOldAgreement != None:
    db_session.add(postApproveOldAgreement)
db_session.commit()
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: 
Can't attach instance <AgreementT at 0x188e8abedc0>; 
another instance with key (<class 'ets.db.models.AgreementT'>, (20812,), None) is already present in this session.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it using the following approach outlined here, https://www.atemon.com/blog/clone-a-sqlalchemy-db-object-with-new-primary-key/

```
    # Initially
    agreement = db_session.query(AgreementT).filter(AgreementT.id == form['agreementIdManual']).first()
    postApproveOldAgreement = None

    if (someCondition):

        # Clone the current Agreement and erase its ID to make it Insert-eligible: 
        # see https://www.atemon.com/blog/clone-a-sqlalchemy-db-object-with-new-primary-key/
        # Use expunge/make_transient
        db_session.expunge(agreement)
        make_transient(agreement)
        agreement.id = None

        # Modify new cloned agreement as necessary...
        agreement.active = 'Y' # etc.
        
        # De-activate the previous Agreement by **re-fetching** it and 
        # modifying it as necessary 
        postApproveOldAgreement = db_session.query(AgreementT).filter(AgreementT.id == form['agreementIdManual']).first()
        postApproveOldAgreement.active = 'N'

   # Insert and commit
   db_session.add(agreement)
   # Special Case: If postApproveOldAgreement is available, commit it as well 
   if postApproveOldAgreement != None:
      db_session.add(postApproveOldAgreement)
   db_session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 2 instances are referencing the same key(I think because you are using `deepcopy`). You can do this trick using a new instance of the `Agreement`.

```
agreement = db.session.query(Agreement).filter(...).first()
# if some_condition... let's say condition works
agreement_data = deepcopy(agreement.__dict__)

# we don't need id + _sa_instance_state db instance
del agreement_data['id']
del agreement_data['_sa_instance_state']

agreement2 = Agreement(**agreement_data)
agreement2.active = 'N'
session.add(agreement2)
# let's try to change an agreement field
agreement.active = 'new val'
session.commit()
```

Logs:

```
2021-07-30 17:18:22,658 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE agreement SET active=%(active)s WHERE agreement.id = %(agreement_id)s
2021-07-30 17:18:22,658 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00012s] {'active': 'new val', 'agreement_id': 1}
2021-07-30 17:18:22,659 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO agreement (....) VALUES (....) RETURNING agreement.id
....
2021-07-30 17:18:22,660 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by "expunging" the current Agreement from the session and erasing its ID to make it Insert-eligible, while the older Agreement is re-fetched manually. In the end, both will be committed. My new reply shows the code. I based it on https://www.atemon.com/blog/clone-a-sqlalchemy-db-object-with-new-primary-key/